# Java - Global variable in timer

Tags: java, timer

First of all, my mother languaje isn't English so sorry if I say something incorrectly.

I'm trying to do a program in Java with 2 queues (A and B) where I put objets every 0,3 seconds and then, depending on an atributte, it insert other atributte in a variable T1, T2, T3 or T4. Rigth now i'm only trying to put it inside T1, but I can't. This is my program now:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  

Queue<Camion> A = new LinkedList<>();
Queue<Camion> B = new LinkedList<>();
double T1 = 0, T2 = 0, T3 = 0, T4 = 0;

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    int cont = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (cont == 3) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        Camion c = new Camion();
        cont++;
        if (A.size() <= B.size()) {
            A.add(c);
        } else {
            B.add(c);
        }
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, 300, 300);

Timer timer2 = new Timer();
TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (!A.isEmpty()) {
            int T1 = A.poll().getPeso(); //if i don't create T1 i got the error
            System.out.println(T1);
            if (T1 <= 1500) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1700);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
timer2.schedule(task2, 10, 10);

Timer timer3 = new Timer();
TimerTask task3 = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!B.isEmpty()) {
            int T1 = B.poll().getPeso();
            System.out.println(T1);
            if (T1 <= 1500) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1700);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can't use T1, T2, T3 and T4 inside the timer. I get this error:

```
Local variable T1 defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

And if I make it final I can't modify it. How can I do it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you search on [local variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](https://www.google.com/search?q=local+variable+defined+in+an+enclosing+scope+must+be+final+or+effectively+final+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Yes, but still can't fix it :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try and move the declaration line outside the main method making them static fields in the class

```
static double T1 = 0, T2 = 0, T3 = 0, T4 = 0;
public static void main(String args[]) {  
.....
```

Beware you are using several timers, each with it's own thread which means if you use T1 (or T2, etc) in more than one task you may have concurrency issues...